# Django model method returning correct response when called from shell but not when called from template

Tags: python, django, shell, django-models, django-templates

models.py

```
class player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    rounds_played = models.IntegerField()
    rounds_missed = models.IntegerField()
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
    total_points = models.IntegerField()
    bio = models.TextField()
    user_ID = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
    user_m = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(),
    def rounds_record(self):
        return int(100 * self.rounds_played / (self.rounds_played + self.rounds_missed))
    def player_status(self):
        if self.is_active:
            return "Yes"
        return "No"
    def average_points(self):
        return int(self.total_points / self.rounds_played)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

template snippet

```
{% for player in players %}
<div class = "grid-item">
        {{player.player_status}}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm developing a database web app (to learn django) in which players on a team and their statistics are tracked and stored in a psql database. When calling the player_status method from the manage.py shell it returns the correct response, say, for each user, 'yes', 'no'.

However when the method is called from the template the method is returning 'yes', 'yes'. After  some troubleshooting I found that it indeed is returning true for each response. What can I do to fix this problem.

EDIT: I should specify I currently have 2 test users, one storing True and the other storing False in the is_active BooleanField

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post the view code, it's hard to tell if everything is implemented correctly.

I also guess that you show the player name in the template and that you see that it is returning the actual 2 players that you have and not twice the same player (which might explain why you see Yes twice).

Other than that it looks fine and should work.